# How to start a media player object in a activity, and then use that same object and another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, mp3, media-player

Example:

Activity 1: 
main screen.

player = new media player()
player.start() //the sound began

now i have to equalize this same sound in another Activity...

Activity 2:
edition screen

the sound keeps playing and want to stop
example:
player.setVolume(0.0)
player.stop()

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare player as public static in screen1

then you can access this media player in screen 2

like screen1

:

```
public static MediaPlayer player;

player=new MediaPlayer();
```

=================
    ===========

write your code

Screen 2 ::-

if you want to use media player in screen 2 use this code ::-

```
screen1.player.start(); screen1.player.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create Service. Service to host the MediaPlayer and have your Activities communicate with the Service to play and stop songs. Don't forget to call release on the MediaPlayer when you are done. Bind the activity to service
For the sample Equalizer [sample](https://github.com/protocol10/EqualizerUnit). The sample is not integrated with Service it just a seperate unit.

Obtain the **sessionid**  of the MediaPlayer and pass it to equalizer.

Comment: this worked well, including'm using this source to the equalizer, 
is only giving some errors when I open the equalizer the second time, but for now I'll try to solve it yourself ... 

It was possible to capture the id of the player using the above solution ... 

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we are using MediaPlayer, as playing music in itself doesnt really require to have a graphical interface, we usually use a service because only the sound resulting by the playback is needed. 
 - Create the mediaplayer in a service
 - Send somes request to the Service after binding to it, or even by sending broadcasts to it so that it can play, stop, pause, set volume whatever you want.